# Omniture object "s" is not available immediately

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm trying to track Page Load Event. I'm getting **utag.js** from **Omniture**.

I'm also wrapping it with jQuery: `$.getScript` to make sure that script is loaded.

But even then if I try to set my `s.pageName` or `s.t();` I'm getting error that **s is undefined**. If I put a 500 ms timeout everything works fine. But I'm surprised that I need to wait even after script is loaded. Is it a common practice with Omniture?

I'm new to the Omniture, it might be very obvious thing for the more experienced users of Omniture.

Comment: It depends on how Adobe Analytics (Omniture) is implemented in Tealium

Answer (score 0):

utag.js is a Tealium loader, which I assume has Adobe Analytics code within it. The only thing that would prevent s from being defined after utag.js being loaded would be that the appmeasurement code is being loaded asynchronously.

You can find more about asynchronous loading here: https://tealium.com/blog/standard/asynchronous-tagging/

I would expect that once you switched to synchronous loading, the variables after utag.js will be able to reference the appmeasurement library.

Answer (score 0):

App Measurement is not designed to be loaded asynchronously. I would suggest adding a "flag" that will indicate when utag.js has loaded and then reference the s.object.